# VFS return files with backslash as "IMAGINARY"

Tags: java, sftp, vfs

I have an SFTP server where i store folders whose name contains (backslash) and when i try to get that resource, the type of the resource is "IMAGINARY". Any idea what the problem is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - we must decode the filename and replace '\' with '\\'